# How do I go from a Maven Dynamic web project to some executable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Maven Dynamic web project in Spring - I can run this in eclipse with a tomcat server and serve all my code a web page via localhost.

I am looking to create an executable which can be ran locally on a machine with no internet connection and when ran will serve the web project to a specified localhost URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have included an embedded server (like tomcat) as a dependency in you POM.xml file, then you have to `Right Click on your Project -> Run as -> Maven Install`. This will build a Maven Executable Jar file in the target folder of your Maven Application.

Take the Jar file and Run it from command line using

`java -jar <jarfilename>.jar`

Answer (score 1):

After building project you will have `<project_name>.war` file created in `target` folder inside the project.
You should deploy it to a J2EE application server, like: Glassfish, JBoss Wildfly, etc.